# ratingbar not setting when notifyDataSetChanged is called

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged, ratingbar

I have a listview with ratingbars. Initially the rating is zero for all. When I give a rating to any one ratingbar, the selected rating is uploaded to server and on successful uploadation, I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` so that the `listview` gets updated with the latest values. But its not setting the rating bar with the value uploaded to server instead it shows zero rating as before. When I go to other page and come back, now the rating is set properly. Am I doing something wrong in my `getView()`?

```
public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OrderModel> {

private Context mContext;
int resource;
private ArrayList<OrderModel> mListData = new ArrayList<OrderModel>();
private String userid, prdid;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;   


public OrderAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<OrderModel> mListData) {
    super(mContext, resource, mListData);
    this.resource = resource;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mListData = mListData;
    sharedpreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

        v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);


        holder.rate = (RatingBar)v.findViewById(rate);



        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }



    holder.rate.setRating(Float.parseFloat(item.getRate()));
    if(holder.rate.getRating()>0) {
        holder.rate.setIsIndicator(true);
    }else{
        holder.rate.setIsIndicator(false);
    }


    holder.rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            uploadrating(String.valueOf(rating), position, ratingBar);
        }
    });

    return v;
}



class ViewHolder {

    ImageView image;
    TextView titletxt, ordereddttxt, delvrdttxt, ordernotxt, statustxt;
    RatingBar rate;
}

private void uploadrating(final String rating, final int position, final RatingBar rate){

    userid=sharedpreferences.getString("userid","");
    prdid = mListData.get(position).getPrdid();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLUtil.UPLOADRATING,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(obj.getInt("Ack")==1){
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, obj.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            rate.setIsIndicator(true);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("user_id", userid);
            params.put("product_id", prdid);
            params.put("score", rating);
            return params;

        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call item.setRate() at some point or else the item doesn't save the new rating.